# Bootstrap Accordion

Tags: bootstrap-theme

This is the code I have used in the *paragraph--faq-group.html.twig* template file. The output is coming as usual, but when I click on the accordion tab, every tab is expanded.

I want only one tab to be open at a time.

```
{%
  set classes = [
    'paragraph',
    'paragraph--type--' ~ paragraph.bundle|clean_class,
    view_mode ? 'paragraph--view-mode--' ~ view_mode|clean_class,
    not paragraph.isPublished() ? 'paragraph--unpublished'
  ]
%}
{% block paragraph %}
 <div class="accordion accordion-flush" id="accordionFlushExample">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-heading">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapse">
        {{ content.field_faq_quest }}
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="flush-collapse" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-heading" data-bs-parent="#accordionFlushExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">{{ content.field_faq_answer }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock paragraph %}
```

Comment: this behavior usually means that the buttons have the same class/id's and the js is triggering all of them